# How to create label and check box dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to create label and check box dynamically.
when i enter text in text box and give submit button,a check box and label with the text i entered in text box should be created..How to create ?

Answer (score 29):

For the label try this:

```
var newlabel = document.createElement("Label");
newlabel.setAttribute("for",id_from_input);
newlabel.innerHTML = "Here goes the text";
parentDiv.appendChild(newlabel);
```

Answer (score 17):

I think you want this..

```
//html
<div id="container">
<input id="test" type="text"  >
<input value="add" type="button"  onClick="add()">
</div>

//js
<script>
var i=0;
function add(){    
    if (document.getElementById('test').value!='') 
    {   
        i++;  
        var title   =document.getElementById('test').value;
        var node = document.createElement('div');        
        node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" id="check' + i + '" name="check' + i + '"><label for="check' + i + '">'+ title +'</label>';       
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(node);    
    }
}
</script>
```